# Can refugees who have obtained Dutch citizenship lose it?

Tags: netherlands, refugees

Many refugees in NL are becoming Dutch citizens.

Is there any law that allows NL to withdraw their NL nationality?  I am not asking about the obvious reasons, like if they are a threat to the country of they made crimes, I am particularly asking about just withdraw the nationality because they didn't get it in the normal migration process but through becoming refugees so they got permanent benefits while being refugee is a temporary case.

Comment: Why the Netherlands specifically?

Comment: How do you define "temporary"?  Many refugees continue to be unable to return to their original country of nationality for far longer than the 5-year residence requirement for naturalization in the Netherlands.  Some people are even born as refugees and live their entire lives as refugees.  It _may be_ temporary in some cases, but that doesn't mean that it _is_ temporary in every case.  (Also, upon naturalization, the refugee ceases to be a refugee as a matter of law.)

Comment: Most (?) world states do not consider revocation of citizenship relevant in context of punishment. That is, they might kill their citizen, but they won't make them a non-citizen.

Comment: @einpoklum there are of course exceptions.

Comment: @phoog people are never born refugees. People are born "holding refugee status" because the host countries refuse to recognize them or because being a refugee is profitable, but they're not *actually* refugees.

Comment: @littleadv in what sense is someone "holding refugee status" not a refugee?

Comment: @phoog in a literal sense.

Comment: @littleadv that's nonsense.  A child born in a refugee camp is a refugee because the host country gives the child refuge.  This is true unless the host country's law grants the child citizenship at birth, so whether the child is a refugee and whether the child "holds refugee status" are the same question.  People don't stay in these camps because it's profitable.

Comment: @phoog really? What about Palestinians in "refugee camps" in Palestine? Aren't they in their own country that "doesn't give them refuge"? In fact, to the best of my knowledge it is only Palestinians who're allowed to "inherit" the refugee status, not every child born in "refugee camp".

Comment: @littleadv sure, one can argue about whether those people are properly called refugees by people who recognize Palestinian sovereignty over those camps, but there are certainly Palestinian refugee camps in other countries as well.  As to the inheritance of refugee status by children of refugees, consider what happens when a child is born in a refugee camp, or indeed to any refugee parents, camp or no: it either acquires the nationality of the host country or becomes a refugee (unless it can be deported to another country, which generally won't be the case).

Comment: @phoog same is true to other countries as well. In fact, many middle eastern countries passed laws explicitly to forbid from the Palestinians from changing their status, forcing them into being "refugees" for generations. There's no justification for that other than antisemitism. If a child is born in a refugee camp and doesn't acquire a status in the host country then the host country is doing something wrong and should be dealt with. Maybe the said refugees chose a wrong host country.

Comment: @littleadv Consider Austria then. There, a child born to a refugee will not only fail to get the Austrian citizenship but can even be stateless (e.g. a child born to an unmarried Syrian mother wouldn't inherit the mother's citizenship under Syrian law). There is absolutely no path to citizenship by birth for the children of foreign citizens in Austria without any exception for refugees nor for people in danger of being stateless. I don't necessarily disagree that those countries are doing something wrong but it's a lot more common than you surmise.

Comment: @Relaxed stateless people are not refugees - they're stateless. That child didn't run away from persecution, their mother did. That child, technically, has no connection to Syria at all, they're not even Syrian citizens. There are a whole bunch of conventions and international agreements of what to do with stateless people, but they're not refugees just because they're stateless.

Comment: @littleadv stateless people may or may not be refugees, and they may even be refugees in one sense of the word but in another sense. Specifically, a child born of refugee parents may be seemed a refugee by a host country because that's the legal approach the country has adopted to avoid deporting the child, while there's no obvious provision for such a child in the refugee convention.  But whether the child is stateless depends on the nationality law parents' country or countries of nationality.  I think where you're going wrong is the idea that "refugee" implies "running away." It doesn't.

Comment: @littleadv the defining aspects of a refugee are presence outside the country of nationality and the inability to return, not having run away. For example, someone could be lawfully in some other country when war breaks out back home. The person becomes a refugee without having run away. The fact that some countries' laws allow children to be born in refugee camps without acquiring status is precisely the situation I was referring to in the comment to which you took exception. Even if this is the host country "doing something wrong," it doesn't change the fact that the child is born a refugee.

Comment: @phoog no, what changes that fact is that child is not outside country of nationality. In Relaxed' example the child is stateless. For the Palestinians  - they never had a country of nationality, and some of them are now Jordanian or Israeli nationals and living in these countries, or living in Palestine itself. Stateless doesn't make a person refugee. People milking charities and governments for generations are not refugees. Countries who force people to live in "refugee camps" for political reasons should be dealt with, but these people are no longer refugees, either.

Comment: @littleadv not every child born in a refugee camp is stateless, and indeed statelessness presents some different issues as well as some of the same issues as refugees, which is why there's a separate convention addressing those issues, and perhaps some people milk the refugee system when they shouldn't be (though I've never seen any evidence that this happens in a widespread basis), but none of that means that there aren't children who are refugees from birth.

Comment: @phoog I've seen. I had someone at one of my previous work places present themselves "I'm a Palestinian refugee". The person was born in Atlanta, GA, native US citizen, has never been persecuted in their entire live, and lives at the place of their choice. When I, an actual former refugee, asked them "What exactly makes you a refugee" - the answer was "my grandfather had to flee Palestine because Jews". So, here.

Comment: @littleadv what charity or government are they milking? You are conflating several issues that are unrelated except by the fact that they concern refugees. None of the several former refugees I know describe themselves as such. You seem to hold out Palestinians as representing all refugees when the opposite is true. I've been to a camp in Africa where people have lived since the mid 1990s. Is that "temporary"? To get back to the question at hand, should a person in the Netherlands subject to the same persecution be denaturalized and sent back if the political situation changed tomorrow?

Comment: @phoog if the political situation in the home country changes tomorrow and they no longer subject to persecution? If they're refugees then yes, absolutely. If the Netherlands decided to accept them as naturalized citizens then they should be treated just as any other citizen. If the host country keeps them in tents for decades then they should be considered persecuted there just as well and move somewhere where they'll be treated humanely if their original home is still (or forever, as in case with Palestinians) unavailable.

Comment: @littleadv So what? In my scenario, the parent is a refugee, the child is stateless, that's an example of a country's law deliberately making it unreasonably hard for the children of refugees to acquire citizenship and normalise their status, something you speculated only exists in Arab countries due to antisemitism.

Comment: Importantly, Palestinian refugees status and access to support does not depend on the host countries' citizenship law. You yourself wrote that many have become citizen where they live, without ceasing to be recognised as refugees. In fact, that's one of the reasons frequently invoked to criticise the UNRWA definition and its difference with the UNHCR definition. So why bring up the whole Palestinian refugee question in this discussion?

Comment: @Relaxed I didn't say it only exists in Arab countries due to antisemitism, I said that Arab countries deliberately do that due to antisemitism. Other countries may be deliberately doing it due to other types of xenophobia, it doesn't make it better or worse or different.  But it doesn't make the stateless people refugees, it just makes them stateless.

Comment: @littleadv Sure, stateless people are stateless, they also may or may not be refugees. The two are closely related and ending statelessness is part of the UNHCR mandate. In any case, Austria is an example of a country failing to provide a status to the children of refugees and that's desperately common around the world so I still fail to understand what your initial point was, exactly.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there aren't and that's not because the Netherlands is especially generous with its citizenship (it isn't). In fact, in the Netherlands, the conditions for a refugee to become a citizen are [exactly the same](https://asylumineurope.org/reports/country/netherlands/content-international-protection/status-and-residence/naturalisation/) as for other categories of migrants (and those permits are also temporary in nature). The conditions that can trigger the loss of that citizenship are also identical (residence outside the Netherlands and acquisition of a foreign citizenship).

Importantly, to apply for naturalisation, you need to have resided in the country for 5 years and fulfill several other requirements, meaning that while the original claim to residence might have been contingent (whether it is international protection, work, or family), an applicant will have laid down roots in the country and their situation is not so temporary anymore.

Honestly, this question makes very little sense to me. There are countries that deprive large number of citizens who still reside in the country of their citizenship but that's generally regarded as something only very oppressive regimes do (think Myanmar). It's also up to the host country to provide a procedure for naturalisation for refugees (there are many countries who do not, e.g. in the Middle East) but if you do have one then it makes sense to treat new citizens as full citizens with the same rights and duties as all other citizens.

What about people who were born Dutch? They didn't go through the “normal migration process” either, whatever that is. Do you think the law should make it possible to strip them of their citizenship at any time for no reason? Or would this kind of revocable half-citizenship be reserved for erstwhile refugees?

Comment: The _Rijkswet op het Nederlanderschap_ enumerates the mechanisms whereby Dutch nationality may be lost precisely and exhaustively, as I suspect you know.  It wouldn't take very long to work through them and see whether any would fit this question (as far as I recall, of course they don't, so +1 to this answer).  I will also make a note under the question about the supposedly "temporary" nature of refugee status.  Also, there are other requirements for naturalization, aren't there, such as an integration test?  Do refugees have to pass this test as well to naturalize?

Comment: @phoog As far as I know, yes, they do in the Netherlands. They don't in France for example, which has an accelerated path to citizenship for refugees (which is why I pointed out that the Netherlands doesn't seem especially generous and it's odd to expect their citizenship to be somehow more questionable).